# Sorry, my bot code is having an issue when hosted to Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to save user data in context using

```
context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<bool>("AccessTokenValue", false);
```

and then trying to get this value using:

```
bool exist;
context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<bool>("AccessTokenValue",out exist);
```

but I am getting this error when using Bot framework and also after hosting this app to Teams.

> Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.

I guess this is because it is not finding `AccessTokenValue` in the context. But I can't figure out a way to hold value in context.

Interesting thing is that when using Bot Emulator I am not getting this error. Its working fine. Also if hosted to Microsoft teams few users can access it without any issues but new users are facing this issue.

Comment: There was a temporary issue with the default state client on September 15th.  The bug has been fixed, and the code you've provided in your question should work.  Please try it again.